# Need NSButtonCell display only column of sub-dictionary value

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have a cell-based `NSTableView`, `NSDictionary` controller, where each dictionary row has a 'value' that's itself a sub-dictionary.  This sub-dictionary 'value' has a bool and int with keys of 'score' and 'value' - this indicates for the given key, score (pass was achieved T/F) and its value.  All contents are displayed only.

I want to expose the sub-dictionary value fields, and the parent key as individual columns bound as

value.score (a boolean)
   value.value (an int)
   key

The table view displays fine but problems arise if a user clicks on the 1st column (my mouseDown: traps as)

```
event:NSEvent: type=LMouseDown loc=(26.1562,187.805) time=34674.7 flags=0 
win=0x6080001ea600 winNum=3393 ctxt=0x0 evNum=2630 click=1 buttonNumber=0 
pressure=1 deviceID:0x0 subtype=0 error:Error setting value for key path 
value.score of object <_NSDictionaryControllerKeyValuePair: 0x608002e40150>
[key: open timer set - value: {
    score = 0;
    value = 4;
}] (from bound object <NSTableColumn: 0x60c000c904f0>   identifier: ): 
[<__NSDictionaryI 0x608005876400> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is 
not key value coding-compliant for the key score.
```

I suspect as it's a button cell which the root problem is the action is being interpreted as a set value event.

I'd like to intercept that action or otherwise prevent altering the column's contents.  A button cell is being used to display an image or alternate image depending on true/false pass state.

Comment: The key `objectValue` is used in view based table views, is the table view view based or is the keypath "value.score"? Is "Editable" of the column switched off?

Comment: Ah, sorry, that was a holdover from attempting a view based tableview - didn't work either; I've amended the question. I have disabled any control setting I can think off (AFAIK).

Comment: Apparently a button cell can't be used for display only. You can display an image using an image cell and a value transformer.